# torch.save() gives : RuntimeError: CUDA error: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I was training a neural network model on GPU but I get the above mentioned error when I use

```
torch.save()
```

to save checkpoints. My question is even though I have a CUDA device why am I getting the mentioned error? My model was running okay on the GPU please see bellow the Output of: nvidia-smi command.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sat Aug 15 09:51:58 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P3    33W /  N/A |   4774MiB /  5934MiB |     97%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7080      C   python3                                     4763MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ python --version
Python 3.8.2

$ python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
1.5.1

$ python -c "import torchvision as torch; print(torch.__version__)"
0.6.1
```

I have even tried the following:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'

torch.save({
                'epoch': epoch + 1,
                'metrics': metrics,
                'model': model.state_dict(),
                'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
            }, name)
```

But nothing worked. I am new to deep learning and still learning PyTorch. Please do pardon my ignorance.

Comment: edit your post with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some other problem. Test this toy example and see if the problem is in `torch.save()` or any other command.

```
import torch
import torchvision

model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model = model.cuda()

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'net')
```